# Getting expected "div" end tag error and I am closing the div on the line it is pointing to. Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: html, meteor

I am working on converting an old node+express application over to meteor to try and get it running on mobile. This is my first real go with meteor beyond the tutorial. I am receiving this error :

```
    While building the application:
    index.html:119: Expected "div" end tag
    ...d="map-canvas"></div>
    ^
```

it appears to my eyes that I am closing all of the div I need to close. Sorry if this is novice but maybe someone can help me point out where I am missing my closing div tag.

Here is lines 114-119 of my project.

```
    114 <div id="bottomNav" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    115    <span>
    116    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Red-Mountain-Park/182530602646"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    117    <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/RedMountainPark"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    118    <a target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com/redmountainpark"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></span></div>
    119 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Sorry to bother you. If there is any other information that I can provide that would help please let me know. Thank you for your time in advance,

Best,
zzrot

Comment: The error is not in here. This is valid HTML. You probably have to check previous lines.

Comment: did you have a repo where we can see this ?

Comment: put all the html you have into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) an pass the link

Comment: I found the unclosed div it was much further up. This application has a lot more errors than that now so I will begin fighting with them on my own. Thank you for your advice and willingness to help. I am so sorry to bother you guys.